# How to get ControlToValidate ID from User Control in a wizard in a popup in a master page - javascript asp.net validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, user-controls, webforms

I want to make my custom javascript validator client function generic and I'm having trouble obtaining the ControlToValidate ID in my function for the user control.

The user control is in a asp:wizard control in a modal popup which is in a page and the whole she-bang uses a master page. I don't know if this information matters.

The following js code works for validation on the user control which is basically a dropdown list. Getting the ID of a single specific control isn't generic at all.

```
function checkCombo(sender, args) {
    var cb = document.getElementById('<%= cmbList.ClientID %>_cmbList');
    args.IsValid = (cb.options[cb.selectedIndex].text != '-- Select --');
}
```

What is supposed to work, doesn't (sender.ControlToValidate). I need to be able to use one function on about 20 different dropdown list user controls.

```
var cb = document.getElementById(sender.controltovalidate);
```

How can I get this control ID in a generic fashion so that my custom javascript validation function will work on all of these user control dropdowns?

Thanks!

--Bob

Comment: Are you using asp.net validation controls.? Why do need ControlToValidate in your custom javascript function?

Comment: Sorry the late reply. It's been so long I forget what I was doing on this but I did manage to work it out. Thanks for responding to my question! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the control value from args without knowing the control itself:

```
function checkCombo(sender, args) {
    args.IsValid = (args.Value != -1);
}
```

This will work if you set the value of the option "-- Select --" to -1.
Anyway, I think you can achieve that with a `RangeValidator` like in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5116098/1495902